# Firebase DebugView events not being filtered out from Analytics data

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode), enabling debug mode on iOS with `-FIRDebugEnabled` should also exclude events from appearing in the main analytics reports:

[image]

I know that I've configured `-FIRDebugEnabled` correctly because I see the events in Firebase's DebugView. However, after an hour or so they also appear in my overall analytics data, which is not desirable. I've tried searching through the Firebase analytics pages for an option to exclude this data or find a query to remove debug events, but I haven't found anything.

I'd like to know if I'm missing something in order to ensure that debug events **only** appear in DebugView and not in the main Analytics section, as the documentation implies.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, you have to use a filter in the Google Analytics property settings in order to get this functionality:

1. Go to the Admin settings page (in Google Analytics, not from Firebase).
2. Click on "Data Settings" for your property.
3. Click on "Data Filters."
4. Click "Create Filter."
5. Choose "Developer Traffic."
6. Set the filter to "active" and then click "create."

I think the Firebase documentation is outdated, since it doesn't happen automatically.